# Cannot convert a function pointer to another function pointer of same type

Tags: c++, function, oop, pointers

The following code doesn't compile:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class A {
        int data;
        bool (*comparer)(int, int);
        bool defaultComparer(int x, int y) {
            return x == y;
        }
    public:
        A() {
            comparer = defaultComparer;
        }
        A(bool (*foo)(int, int)) {
            comparer = foo;
        }

    };
    bool myfunc(int a, int b) {
        return a == b;
    }
    int main()
    {
        A obj(myfunc);
    }
```

The compilation error is:

```
11:12: error: cannot convert 'A::defaultComparer' from type 'bool (A::)(int, int)' to type 'bool (*)(int, int)'
   comparer = defaultComparer;
            ^
```

What is the problem with my code? Is it wrong to assign `comparer` from `defaultComparer`? If yes, then how should I do this?

This is different to "[Function pointer to member function](/q/2402579)", as I don't want to change the type of `comparer`.

Comment: member methods are different of free functions, make your method `static`

Comment: thank you..It worked for me @Jarad42

Comment: I wonder why this question was hailed as duplicate. The other post is different from mine.

Comment: You can use a pointer to a `static` function in `A` as a function pointer, but not a (non-`static`) member function.  So `static bool defaultComparer(int x, int y)` should be fine for you.